# Как настроить браузер мобильного устройства в Netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans

Начал изучать HTML, использую Netbeans 8. Хочу протестировать сайт в браузере android, выбираю устройство на платформе android, нажимаю запустить проект - настроить - в параметрах нажимаю загрузить android sdk - загружаю sdk в zip архиве, потому что обычный не запускается - устанавливаю всё, что выбрано по умолчанию - установка завершается успешно - опять захожу в параметры, указать расположение sdk, указываю папку, куда установил sdk, но netbeans пишет:

> sdk не найден

Что дальше делать, не знаю.

И ещё при запуске `AVD` через `AVD MANAGER` устройство очень долго грузится и пишет

> android wear isnt responding. do yoy want to close it

Но один раз удалось запустить avd и netbeans, вроде-бы нашёл путь, но вылезла ошибка:

> "Подключите устройство андроид и убедитесь что в устройстве включена отладка по usb  компьютер и устройство подключены к одной и той-же сети wi-fi"

Как всё-таки сделать, чтобы я мог просматривать свои веб-страницы в netbeans на android эмуляторе?

Answer (score 2):

Есть намного более комфортные эмуляторы Android, на пример [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)

Comment: А его можно пристыковать к netbeans, чтобы при нажатии кнопки отладка он автоматически запускал браузер мобильного устройства?

Comment: Но за то у него много преймуществ, которые, как по мне с лихвой компенсируют этот недостаток...

Я использовал [shttps][1], и просто обновлял страницу в браузере после изменений...


  [1]: http://smallsrv.com/indexr.htm